# Cascading not saving the reference table data

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, entity

Cascading not saving the details

### Orders table

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
  order_id numeric(10,0) NOT NULL,
  test_id numeric(5,0),
  CONSTRAINT orders_pkey PRIMARY KEY (order_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_order_user_doneby FOREIGN KEY (done_by)
      REFERENCES user_mast (user_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
}
```

### Reference table

```
CREATE TABLE refout_order_hdr
(
  ref_inst_id numeric(8,0),
  status character varying(1),
  ref_out_id numeric(10,0) NOT NULL,
  order_id numeric(10,0),
  CONSTRAINT "refout_order_pkey PRIMARY KEY (ref_out_id)" PRIMARY KEY (ref_out_id),
  CONSTRAINT "ref_out_fkey_order_id order_id)" FOREIGN KEY (order_id)
      REFERENCES orders (order_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

There is a one to many relation between Orders & Refrence(order_Id)

### Entity class for Reference

```
 /**
  * 
  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private long refOutId;
 private CdcInstitutes instMast;
 private String status;
 @JsonIgnore
 private Orders orders;


 //------other getters and setters are there -------------//

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="order_id")
public Orders getOrders() {
    return orders;
}

public void setOrders(Orders orders) {
    this.orders = orders;

 //------other getters and setters are there -------------//
```

### Entity class for Orders

```
private Long orderId;
private TestMast testMast;
private Set<RefoutOrder> refoutOrder; 


@OneToMany(mappedBy="orders", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST } )
public Set<RefoutOrder> getRefoutOrder() {
    return refoutOrder;
}

public void setRefoutOrder(Set<RefoutOrder> refoutOrder) {
    this.refoutOrder = refoutOrder;
}
```

Even though cascading is set while saving the orders entity, reference table orderId is not saving. other fields are set.

//Service Layer

```
for( OrderedListDto orderedListDto : radioOrderList){
            if(orderedListDto != null && orderedListDto.getOrdersDto() != null){
                orderedListDto.getOrdersDto().setTestType(ServiceConstants.TEST_TYPE_RADIALOGY);
                orderedListDto.getOrdersDto().setVisitId(visitDto.getVisitId());
                neworderDtos.add(orderedListDto.getOrdersDto());
            }
        }
        List<OrdersDto> resultList = ordersService.saveOrdersList(new ArrayList<>(neworderDtos));
```

//Save method will be called from here

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public List<OrdersDto> saveOrdersList(List<OrdersDto> ordersList) throws VisitMastException {
        if(ordersList == null){
            //need to throws exception as atleast one order to update or save order.
        }
         List<OrdersDto> resultList = new ArrayList<OrdersDto>();
        for(OrdersDto order: ordersList){
            try{
                order.setInstCode(InstitutionService.getInstCode());
                order.setCreatedDate(new Date());                           order = super.saveOneEntity(order);
                resultList.add(order);

            } catch (GenericException ge) {
                throw new VisitMastException(ge, ge.getRootCauseMessage());
            } catch (InstituteNotFoundException e) {
                throw new VisitMastException(VisitMastException.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "", e, 
                        messageSource.getMessage(CodeEnum.INST_CODE_NOT_FOUND.getValue(), null, Locale.ENGLISH));
            }

        }
        return resultList;
    }
```

saving logic will save one entity at a time

Comment: Where is your DAO or Repository code for insert/save data ?

Comment: Its saving the Orders . DO I need to set manually the orders to Reference Entity ?

Comment: No you should not, I wanted to check your logic on how u r inserting such that it is failing to store the id

Comment: Updated the question. Do I need to change the Cascade type ?

Comment: @Autowired
 private DozerBeanMapper mapper;result = repository.save(mapper.map(dto, entityClass));Saving the value here using Dozer.